# regular expression in String.ReplaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string

I have code that does't like dollar sign that must be vissible in replacement.

```
String s1= "this is amount <AMOUNT> you must pay";
s1.replaceAll("<AMOUNT>", "$2.60");
System.out.print(s1);
```

I have exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference`

I expet to get string `"this is amount $2.60 you must pay"`

How to change my code to have required result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your code like this:

```
    String s1= "this is amount <AMOUNT> you must pay";
    s1 = s1.replaceAll("<AMOUNT>", "\\$2.60");
    System.out.print(s1);
```

1) escape `$` character

2) you need to save the result of `replaceAll` method, so assign it to `s1` again.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to use regular expressions (you don't seem to), use `replace` instead:

```
s1 = s1.replace("<AMOUNT>", "$2.60");
```

Comment: what if I want to replace with regular expressions.?

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal Then use `replaceAll` and escape special characters, but there is no need for a regex in your example.

Comment: Yes in this example it's not requires. I asked just for the sake of my knowledge.

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal If you look at [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) of the various String methods, those that use regular expressions generally take a `String regex` argument, like `split`, `matches` and `replaceAll` for example.

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal And the detail of regex patterns in Java can be found in the [Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: This is a good tutorial if you are interested: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Just use replace instead. No need to use regular expression.

```
s1 = s1.replace("<AMOUNT>", "$2.60");
```

Comment: Don't forget to reassign `s1`! :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions use the special character `$` to indicate a group in the expression. That's why you got confused. If you want the literal thing, just escape it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String s1= "this is amount <AMOUNT> you must pay";
    System.out.print(s1.replaceAll("<AMOUNT>", "\\$2.60"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When not using regex, you should use replace().

Also you should store the resulting string somewhere else, like

```
String s1 = "this is amount <AMOUNT> you must pay";
String s2 = s1.replace("<AMOUNT>", "$2.60");
System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use double slash `\\` before `$` symbol.

```
String s1 = "this is amount <AMOUNT>you must pay";
s1 =s1.replaceAll("<AMOUNT>", "\\$2.60");
System.out.print(s1);
```